# Converting an iphone app to framework

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6, ios7

I am trying to convert my iPhone app(AAA) into framework such that it can be used by other iPhone app(BBB) as an external framework.App BBB will have it's own main.m, appdelegate.h and appdelegate.m files.I wanted to know, whether i have to include my app's(AAA) main.m, appdelegate.h and appdelegate.m files into framework or not?

Comment: No, you don't.  Those are only used to run an application.  Frameworks are not runnable.

Comment: @user2533604 Have you been able to do this? Trying to do the same thing. I don't want to go through creating a new project as a framework and adding all files again, just converting the existing app to a framework.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very good tutorial on creating a framework. I think this is what you are looking for. Just abstract the parts out of your app that you want to share.

[iOS Framework](https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework)